# How to set status bar text color dark for android 5.1.1 of vivo

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm using [ImmersionBar] (https://github.com/gyf-dev/ImmersionBar).
But not support vivo.
Any idea of my problem?
I've search this. Someone say that vivo's code is not open. So I can do nothing about it?

Comment: Setting status bar text / icons color is only support on Android 6.0+

Comment: To make status bar text color dark or light you should dark or light themes.